# Why is Gaussian elimination still being taught when there are more efficient methods?

Tags: linear-algebra, education, gaussian-elimination

> Why is Gaussian elimination still being taught when there are more efficient methods?

By efficient methods I mean less time and effort consuming ways to solve a system of linear equations. I have nothing against learning. I´m just really curious about this.

Comment: I am wondering which method you are referring to.

Comment: Maybe because it is simple and can be done by hand? There are more efficient algorithms for computers but difficult to remember.

Comment: Another argument in favor of Gaussian elimination: Proving its correctness is straightforward.

Comment: Gaussian elimination is the Swiss army knife of matrix algebra because it produces a reduced row-echelon form.  Many theoretical properties are derived insightfully this way.  You would improve your Question if you gave references for what you claim are more efficient methods and placed the claim in some sort of context (efficient for solving what?).

Comment: Cramer´s rule works fine for me, highly consistent and automated  process

Comment: @JorgeRocha it is exponentially in the dimension

Comment: Cramer's rule is actually a very inefficient method for solving linear systems.  You have to compute a bunch of determinants, which is very expensive. Matlab  uses Gaussian  elimination for general dense linear systems, which is a good sign that faster methods aren't available.

Comment: Gaussian elimination is of $O(n^3)$ complexity if no pivoting is required.  Cramer's rule involves the determinant of the (square) matrix, and naive evaluation of the determinant is of exponential complexity.  Gaussian elimination can provide the determinant, again with $O(n^3)$ complexity.

Comment: For a moment there I thought you were referring to LU decomposition. :P

Comment: Do you usually work with $2\times 2$ or $3\times 3$ matrices? Crammer Rule is highly inefficient for matrices of bigger size.

Comment: @BigbearZzz Yes I do, but thank you guys I now have a bigger understanding of why somethings seem to be antiquated but in certain applications they are the best choice

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that
the more efficient methods
are more complicated
and are more efficient
only for large matrices.

The original faster method
was Strassen's.

Here is a typical paper.
found by a Google search for
"solving linear system of equations strassen",
discussing the
effectiveness of
using Strassen's method:

http://www.ibspan.waw.pl/~paprzyck/mp/cvr/research/varia_papers/CMA_S_96.pdf

It says that
Strassen's method was faster for
$n=150$.
For $n=1500$,
Strassen's method
was $30%$ faster.

This paper was written in 1996,
so more recent results
are almost certainly available.

Comment: To be fair, it is still Gaussian elimination. The paper just says it can be implemented more efficiently by using Strassen compared to a naive implementation.